# bootstrap date picker rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
read = ->
   $('#date_picker').datepicker

$(document).ready read
$(document).on "page:load", read
```

This the code I am using the above is how I call the datepicker. I am using date picker rails gem. The below is the form code

```
= simple_form_for :due_on,:url=> admin_requests_path,:method => "get",html: {id: "due_on_filter"}  do |f|
  = f.input :mydate,:disabled => 'disable', :input_html => { :data => {:behaviour => :datepicker },id: "date_picker"}
```

I am not able to get it to work. There are no errors but datepicker just does not work.

This is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
//= require datatable_calls
//= require nprogress
//= require nprogress-turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require chosen_calls
//= require filter_ajax_calls
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require custom
```

---

HTML raw output of the form is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/requests" class="simple_form due_on" id="due_on_filter" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>  
<div class="control-group string required due_on_mydate">
<label class="string required control-label" for="date_picker">
<abbr title="required">*</abbr> Mydate</label>
<div class="controls">
<input class="string required" data-behaviour="datepicker" id="date_picker" name="due_on[mydate]" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is the html that is being outputted, is the id date_picker being set on the form? I dont think you have set your id correctly on the form, could be wrong though..worth checking

Comment: This was the output html 

`<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/requests" class="simple_form due_on" id="due_on_filter" method="get" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>  <div class="control-group string required due_on_mydate"><label class="string required control-label" for="date_picker"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Mydate</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" data-behaviour="datepicker" id="date_picker" name="due_on[mydate]" type="text" /></div></div>
    </form>`

Comment: typo in question ??
`read = ->
   $('#date_picker').datepicker()`

Comment: My bet is that it has something to do with turbolinks. Try to add `//= require jquery.turbolinks` to your application.js to add support for page events

Comment: that did not work @lightswitch05

Answer (score 3):

you sure this js/coffee code works?

Could you try that please:

```
setInterval(function() {
$(function () { 
var datepicker = $('#date_picker');                                                     
        if(datepicker.length) {
            datepicker.datepicker();
            alert("found the element!");
        } else {
            alert("could not find element");
        }    
    });  
}, 4000);
```

Comment: It is returning could not find element.

Comment: Alright so basically we know that the element isn't in dom structure. What happens if you go to that page and wait for 30 seconds or something like that. Does the form gets rendered then and do you get the message "found element"?

Comment: Could you append this into your application.js file "//= require_tree ." maybe something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Edit in your script as

```
$(function(){$("#datepicker").datepicker({
showbuttonPanel: true
});
});
```

and you need to require  `bootstrap` and `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom` files in both js & css application. Now implement the datepicker where ever you want using the datepicker id.